# What is the most efficient way to use the or operator in C?

Tags: c, syntax

I haven't practiced C in a while but is there a way to shorten this statement:

```
 if(!(argv[i] == '+' || argv[i] == '-' || argv[i] == '/' || argv[i] == '*')){

            }
```

Is it a proper syntax to do something like this:

```
argv[i] == '+’,’-’,’*’,’%’ ;
```

Comment: If `argv` is a `char**` (as is conventional), then `argv[i]` is a `char*`, and cannot be treated as a singular `char`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, your suggestion is not valid syntax.

There is no "magic" way. What I'd do is one or more of

- Shorten the left-hand side, by doing e.g. `const char op = argv[i];` then just having `op` in the `if`.
- Use [`strchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr), your expression then becomes `if(strchr("+-/*", argv[i]) == NULL` (this is like Python's `if argv[i] in "+-/9":`).
- Refactor to use some data-driven table design instead. Probably for larger cases than this, though. :)

Comment: Isn't `argv` typically a `char**`?? Then `argv[i]` is a `char*`? And you're treating it as a single `char`.

Comment: @abelenky also the OP treated it as a char. It's only a name

Comment: @FiddlingBits if you use it as command line Input yours would be correct. But you don´t know how `argv` is declared in this case. The OP uses it as a char Array, so he should have a line like `char argv[100];` in his code.